# Running batch file depending on other files from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file which is supposed (among other things) to call another batch file.
The second batch file is depending on files located in the same directory, so, when I try running it from the first batch file, it fails.

Example:

Batch file #1: (Located on C:)

```
@echo  OFF
call C:\Tests\Tests.bat
```

Output: "Could Not Find C:\Tests\Tests.txt

Reason: Both Tests.bat and Tests.txt are located under: C:\Tests while I'm calling it from C:.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot,
Idan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%-dp0` within a batch file to get the path of the currently executing batch file. You can use that path every time you need to access a file from that directory. For example:

```
call "%~dp0\Tests.bat"
for /f "usebackq ..." ... in ("%~dp0\someFile") do ...
```

Another option is to temporarily set your current directory to the same path at the top of a batch script using PUSHD. From that point on you don't have to worry about providing the path to the other commands. Just be sure to use POPD before the script exits. That way the script will not impact any script that may have called it.

```
pushd "%~dp0"
rem Do you work
popd
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there a way to do it without changing the directory? (I'm asking because I might need to call different batch files, located in different locations).

Comment: @Idanis - That is what I tried to address in the first part of my answer. Every line of code that refers to a file can include the path from `%~dp0` path as appropriate. I've also updated my answer concerning PUSHD